# FME : Populate a column in Table A with the value(max) from StatisticCalculator transformer from table B

Tags: fme-form

**What I'm trying to do :**

I have two shp file readers as input. I'd like to calculate the maximum value in column 1 of Table B and then populate a new field in Table A with that same value (same value in all rows). Additional information, there is no common fields or geometry between them so I can't perform a Join...

**What I've tried so far :**

I used the StatisticCalculator transformer to return the max value from the column in table B. I then thought that I'm basically trying to declare a variable, so I used the the VariableSetter and Retriever  - defining a global variable. Thinking it would be available in the Attribute Manager that I use on Table A (to create the column and populate with my global variable).
However the attribute 'max' is only available if I connect the VariableRetriever as an input. The result is the AttributeManager creates a new feture and populates the new column in that specific row (i.e. the row containing the new feature). Where as, I don't want to create a new feature, but I do want to copy the value from the max value from the StatisticCalculator into every row of the new column...

I'm fairly new to FME and I imagine there is an easy solution... anyone know what I'm missing ?

[image: Basic model]

Comment: create a unique number between tables and use the Feature Merger https://engage.safe.com/transformers/feature-merger/#:~:text=Merges%20the%20attributes%20and%2For,key%20attribute%20values%20and%20expressions. then spilt out using the unique number.

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks - I was barking up the wrong tree with the variableSetter / Retriever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK so with the comment of @Mapperz (thanks) I've got a simple solution (I was sure there would be...). Use the attribute manager to create a join field on both tables with a common value, then pass the resulting tables into the feature merger and bingo... no need to use the VariableSetter or VariableRetriever.

[image]

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to create that join field. You can type the same constant value directly into the Requestor/Supplier fields in the FeatureMerger. It really doesn't make a difference, but I thought I'd point it out.